# Strange error in batch file when handling a file path with Program Files (x86)

Tags: windows, batch-file, escaping, environment-variables

I am writing a batch script to remove quotes from the JAVA_HOME env variable and am getting an error only when JAVA_HOME is set with "Program Files (x86)" in the path. My JAVA_HOME variable is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`(no quotes are in the value)

```
    set lastChar=%JAVA_HOME:~-1%
    set firstChar=%JAVA_HOME:~0,1%

    echo Begin
    if '^%firstChar%=='^" (
        echo JAVA_HOME starts with a quote

        if '^%lastChar%=='^" (
            echo JAVA_HOME ends with a quote
            set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:~1,-1%    ###Error occurs on this line
        )
    )
    echo END
```

The output is:

```
 Begin
 \Java\jdk1.7.0_7 was unexpected at this time.
```

As you can see, none of the lines after "echo Begin" are run. If I comment out the line `set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:~1,-1%` then the program runs all the way to END. Also, if I change the JAVA_HOME env var to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79`, the script runs fine without commenting out that line.

Why is this one line giving me this error?

Comment: I rather think the syntax error occurs with the `if` statement immediately after the `echo Begin` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with problematic characters within environment variables is to use delayed expansion. You can do string substitution to remove any quotes. I am assuming you want the modified value to persist after the batch script ends, so I use a FOR variable to transfer the modified value across the ENDLOCAL barrier.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "val=!JAVA_HOME:"=!"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("!val!") do endlocal&set "JAVA_HOME=%%A"
```

It is possible to do this from the command line, without using batch. But it is a bit tricky to get the proper escape sequences

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('cmd /v:on /c echo !JAVA_HOME:^"^=!') do @set "JAVA_HOME=%A"
```

Comment: String substituion is a much better approach to removing chars within an env var. Also enableDelayedExpansion was a big help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`^` escapes other characters. So `^%` means no percent sign to CMD. Use `^^%firstchar%==^^` to escape the caret so it isn't escaping the `%` and `"`.

Comment: I think he wants to escape the double-quote, he's trying to compare it to his variable

Comment: Setx will replace anything in the path. `setx path <pathyouwant>` so `setx path c:\windows` wouldreplace `"c:\windows"` in the path.

Comment: Talking about the `if` line, I think he's trying to escape the quote so he can compare it to his variable

Comment: I showed him/her how to escape the caret on the left. If you are right, as is likely, then s/he needs not to escape it on the right. However it is possible s/he is comparing carets not quotes.